# Selenium - Get Text Attribute of Element

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a table and store in list/dict with intent to add this data to a Pandas Dataframe. I am having issues getting the desired output in my dictionary though.

```
# import currencies
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.worlddata.info/currencies/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

table_identifier = 'table.std100.hover[data-linktitles="Details and exchange rates: _country_"]'
table = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, table_identifier)))

currency = []

for tr in table.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody/tr'):
    iso = tr.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/td[1]')
    ctr = tr.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/td[3]')
    temp = {
        'iso': iso,
        'country': ctr
    }
    currency.append(temp)

print(currency)
```

---

When I run this code I get the following output (trimmed fro the first 2 tr tag contents). I'm not sure why the data in for tr is just blank values and the data in the second tr is giving me these very unexpected values in `iso` and `country` field.

```
[
{'iso': [], 'country': []},
{'iso': [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d60827d43f7fc7f7b91dec76d4ab861c", element="399a04e6-e4e5-468b-88bb-7307083aacd3")>], 'country': [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d60827d43f7fc7f7b91dec76d4ab861c", element="37b7b061-1983-4703-ac39-b28d386f9a98")>]
},
```

I tried to update the code to access the `.text` attribute (where `iso` & `ctr` is defined as well as in the `temp` array. Each return an error saying there is no `.text` element.

```
line 20, in <module>
    iso = tr.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/td[1]').text
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

---

**Question:** How do I access the text elements that exist in the tbody/tr/td tags?

I'm not sure the loop (or dict assignment) is correct but for now I can't even access the text to start to debug the rest of code. I have also added a screenshot with the relevant page HTML for context

[image]

Comment: I've also seen others download some Chrome driver that is locally saved and pointed to somewhere in `webDriver` function. Is that the issue? Trying to look up what that driver is and where I would even reference it in this code if so

Comment: When fetching `.text`, I noticed you're calling `.text` on a `.findElements()` call - which returns a list. Try something like `iso = tr.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/td[1]')[0].text` to grab the first element in the list.

Comment: I got a new error @CEH - at this point I will call that progress! `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: That tells me `.findElements()` might be returning an empty list, if [0] is out of range. You could try a singular `findElement()` call instead, and check that the WebElement is not null before trying to access `.text`

Comment: I'm going to try to loop through the elements but there must be a easier way...

Comment: There are two different issues I see here so I wrote up a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first call to `iso = tr.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/td[1]')` is returning a null web element because the first `tr` in the list has no `td` elements - this is the table header row in the HTML sample provided.

This causes an issue later on when calling `.text`, because it's called on a null WebElement. This partially explains the later error mentioned - `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`. Although, the root cause of this issue is calling `.text` on a List - this was discussed in comments above.

To fix the above issues mentioned, I recommend adding a null check before accessing the List. Then, grab the 1st element in the List, which returns a single WebElement. `.text` can safely be called, once it is ensured that `td` is not null and is not a List.

```
for tr in table.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody/tr'):
    iso = tr.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/td[1]')
    ctr = tr.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/td[3]')
    if (len(iso) > 0 and len(ctr) > 0): // check that list has items
    
        temp = {
        'iso': iso[0].text, // access 1st element in the list & get its text
        'country': ctr[0].text
        }
        currency.append(temp)
```

Comment: Looks like some of your updates are C++ maybe? I don't believe Python has '&&' operator so would just use `and`. Is `.size` a valid operator here? I'm not getting an error on the `if` line after updating other syntax `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'`

Comment: I learned programming in VBA so not assigning variables seems so crazy to me still. Not sure what `iso` will default to so not sure what arguments I can use to check

Comment: Updated the example to use python syntax, including `and` and `len()`.

Comment: This did the trick (once converted to Python). Can you update the code so I can accept solution? Need to change the `if` test to `if (len(iso) > 0 and len(ctr) > 0):` and remove the brackets that were added under `if` (remove `{` and `}`)

Comment: Sure thing, the answer has been updated.